# When clicking on close button change element to inital state - javascript

Tags: javascript, web, button, queryselector

I'm trying to make a close button to collapse the iframe and restore the thumbnail which can be clicked to open the iframe. When I try it with a specific id it is working, but I would like to make it working for any iframe which opens.

Here is my code so far:

```
        <span id="close-button" onClick="document.getElementById('loading').style.display='none';
                                         document.getElementById('close-button').style.display='none';
                                         document.getElementByClassName('games').classList.remove('play');
                                         document.querySelectorAll('.games .iframe').style.display='none';
                                         document.querySelectorAll('.games .thumbnail').style.display='initial';
                                         document.querySelectorAll('.games .play-button').style.display='initial';
                                         document.querySelectorAll('.games .name').style.display='initial';">
        </span>
```

This is the code which is working, but then only for one specific game:

```
<span id="close-button" onClick="document.getElementById('loading').style.display='none';
                                         document.getElementById('close-button').style.display='none';
                                         document.getElementById('game3').classList.remove('play');
                                         document.querySelector('#game3 .iframe').style.display='none';
                                         document.querySelector('#game3 .thumbnail').style.display='initial';
                                         document.querySelector('#game3 .play-button').style.display='initial';
                                         document.querySelector('#game3 .name').style.display='initial';">
        </span>
```

Looking forwards for helping anwsers..

Answer (score 0):

You should start with putting all the `open` and `close` code in its own javascript file and in a function to make it more readable.

Then pass the id of the iframe you want to close in the function. Now you can easily create more buttons to close different iframes.

You can use `querySelector` on the game element, so it's easier to search for all the children of the game element.

```js
<span id="close-button" onClick="openGame('game3')"></span>
<span id="close-button" onClick="openGame('game4')"></span>
```

and then

```js
function openGame(id) {
    document.getElementById('loading').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('close-button').style.display='none';
    const game = document.getElementById(id);
    game.classList.remove('play');
    game.querySelector('.iframe').style.display='none';
    game.querySelector('.thumbnail').style.display='initial';
    game.querySelector('.play-button').style.display='initial';
    game.querySelector('.name').style.display='initial';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I put it now in it's own javascript with onlick events, but how can I get the value of the id from the play() function to the collapse() function, as I only have one close button to appear for all games?

```
<span id="close-button" onclick="collapse();"></span>


        function play(id, link)
        {
            const game = document.getElementById(id);
            game.classList.add("play");
            game.querySelector(".iframe").src=link;
            game.querySelector(".iframe").style.display="initial";
            game.querySelector(".thumbnail").style.display="none";
            game.querySelector(".play-button").style.display="none";
            game.querySelector(".name").style.display="none";
            document.getElementById("close-button").style.display="initial";
        }
        
        function collapse(id)
        {
            const game = document.getElementById(id);
            game.classList.remove("play");
            game.querySelector(".iframe").style.display="none";
            game.querySelector(".thumbnail").style.display="initial";
            game.querySelector(".play-button").style.display="initial";
            game.querySelector(".name").style.display="initial";
            document.getElementById("close-button").style.display="none";
        }
```